# VSCode Platformio Schedule.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++

I suppose this might be more an environment question regarding Platform.io and VSCode, as my code works great in the Arduino IDE, however the lack of syntax highlighting is driving me mad.

I've setup a Platform.io project in VSCode, copied my code across and setup my board (Wemos D1 Mini)

My `platformio.ini` file looks like:

```
[env:wemos_d1_mini32]
platform = espressif32
board = wemos_d1_mini32
framework = arduino
```

There are a couple of headers that are highlighted as having errors:

```
#include "FirebaseESP8266.h"
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
```

I've installed FirebaseESP8266 to my project from the PlatformIO libraries, however it still says:

> include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit
>   (C:\Users\Greg\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\Lovebox\src\main.cpp).C/C++(1696)

If I try to build it errors with `src\main.cpp:1:22: fatal error: Schedule.h: No such file or directory`

As for the ESP8266WiFi library, it simply says `cannot open source file "ESP8266WiFi.h"`

Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Did you install the libraries you need / use?

You could do it either via the platformio screen or add the names directly to the 
`platformio.ini`

```
lib_deps =
    Firebase ESP8266 Client@>=2.7.8
```

And additionally `ESP8266WiFi.h` is an ESP8266 library
for the ESP32 you should use the lib `#include <WiFi.h>`

EDIT: To update the project libraries, select 'Update Project Libraries' from the project tasks.